# Fourier transform of a tilted line function

Tags: fourier-transform

Assume a line function (line segment to ensure integration):

$$y = a\cdot x + b$$

What is the Fourier transform of the line segment? Intuitively, it may give a sinc function, but actually not.

Comment: A line is not directly $\L_1$ integrable and Fourier transformable in the most common sense. Can you give more details about what you expect?

Answer (score 2):

The Fourier transform of polynomial functions exists in the domain of generalized functions, or distributions. The (non-unitary) Fourier transform of

$$f(t)=t^n\tag{1}$$

is given by (cf. entry 308 in [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Distributions))

$$F(\omega)=2\pi j^n\delta^{(n)}(\omega)\tag{2}$$

where $\delta^{(n)}$ is the $n^{th}$ generalized derivative of the Dirac delta impulse.

Consequently, the Fourier transform of

$$f(t)=at+b\tag{3}$$

is given by

$$F(\omega)=2\pi \left[ j\cdot a\, \delta'(\omega)+b\,\delta(\omega)\right]\tag{4}$$

If you want the Fourier transform of a line segment, i.e., of a line multiplied by a rectangular function, you need to convolve $(4)$ with an appropriately chosen sinc function.

Answer (score 0):

We know that the Fourier transform of the step function (or Heaviside function) is given by $$U(\omega)=\pi\delta(\omega)-\frac{j}{\omega}$$

A ramp function (which would be a linear function starting from $x=0$) can be written as

$$f(x) = xu(x)$$

where $u(x)$ is the step function. So using the property of derivation in the frequency domain we get that

$$F(\omega)=j\frac{d}{d\omega}\left(U(\omega)\right)=j\pi\delta'(\omega)-\frac{1}{\omega^2}$$

If you want to modify the slope or the starting point of the ramp (i.e. $a$ and $b$ in your question), the procedure is exactly the same as Fourier transform is linear and you would be multiplying by a scalar and adding a constant in the time domain.

Answer (score 0):

Function f(t) is defined in  tf plqane by stright-line segments joining (-T,0) to (0,1) to (T,9) with f(t)=0 outside |t|>T.  The solution can be seen in :  K.F.Riley, M.P.Hobson, S.J.Bence; Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering; Cambridge University Press 2006; Chapter 13, Integral Transforms